# C++ Quicksort with vectors

Tags: c++, vector, pass-by-reference, quicksort

The quicksort function works perfectly fine as ive tried it with the standard array.  When using vectors however, I get an error message saying swap function doesnt take 3 arguments. Any help would be appreciated.

```
void quicksort(vector<int> &vec, int L, int R) {
    int i, j, mid, piv;
    i = L;
    j = R;
    mid = L + (R - L) / 2;
    piv = vec[mid];

    while (i<R || j>L) {
        while (vec[i] < piv)
            i++;
        while (vec[j] > piv)
            j--;

        if (i <= j) {
            swap(vec, i, j); //error=swap function doesnt take 3 arguments
                i++;
                j--;
        }
        else {
            if (i < R)
                quicksort(vec, i, R);
            if (j > L)
                quicksort(vec, L, j);
            return;
        }
    }
}

void swap(vector<int> v, int x, int y) { 
    int temp = v[x];
    v[x] = v[y];
    v[y] = temp;

}

int main() {
    vector<int> vec1;
    const int count = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        vec1.push_back(1 + rand() % 100);
    }
    quicksort(vec1, 0, count - 1);

}
```

Comment: Are you saying that i should use offset notation rather subscript notation?

Comment: You tried to use your swap function before declaring it. The compiler hasn't seen it yet. Instead, it is looking at `std::swap` from the standard library, which only takes two arguments. You need to declare your functions before trying to use them.

Comment: using namespace std; introduces the std swap function into your namespace and will be declared and defined before your use of your own swap. Move your swap definition higher up and fix the bug where it should be taking the vector by reference rather than by value (copy).

Comment: `using namespace std;`, while of course bad practice, is not at fault here. `std::swap` will be caught by ADL even without it.

Comment: So basically, I had to put the swap function above the quicksort function. and it's now working. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Good point. Re-opened.

Comment: This question does not demonstrate any research effort (and the sample code is far from minimal (in the sense of [mcve])).

Answer (score 1):

See

```
void quicksort(vector<int> &vec, int L, int R)
```

and

```
void swap(vector<int> v, int x, int y)
```

The first parameter does not use reference.

Answer (score 0):

Like various comment say, problem is that your version of swap is being confused with std::swap.  You can fix it by either moving the implementation of swap before you use it or add a declaration before you use it.

Also per Devin's answer, pass by reference so you get the swapped values back.

Here is the fixed code:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
void swap(vector<int>& v, int x, int y);

void quicksort(vector<int> &vec, int L, int R) {
    int i, j, mid, piv;
    i = L;
    j = R;
    mid = L + (R - L) / 2;
    piv = vec[mid];

    while (i<R || j>L) {
        while (vec[i] < piv)
            i++;
        while (vec[j] > piv)
            j--;

        if (i <= j) {
            swap(vec, i, j); //error=swap function doesnt take 3 arguments
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        else {
            if (i < R)
                quicksort(vec, i, R);
            if (j > L)
                quicksort(vec, L, j);
            return;
        }
    }
}

void swap(vector<int>& v, int x, int y) {
    int temp = v[x];
    v[x] = v[y];
    v[y] = temp;

}

int main() {
    vector<int> vec1;
    const int count = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        vec1.push_back(1 + rand() % 100);
    }
    quicksort(vec1, 0, count - 1);

}
```